# Javascript Select Text Changer having glitches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a engraving tool for an e-commerce site, and I cant seem to see why the text changer is glitchy. It seems to work, but then it seems it gets hung up. Not sure what it is.

Here is my javascript code:

```
        /**Load Text**/
jQuery(function() {
    $source=jQuery(".source-text");
    $output=jQuery(".output-text-div");
    $source.keyup(function() {
       $output.text($source.val());
    });
});

//Text Loader FOnt Change
    var $textpreview = jQuery(".output-text-div");

jQuery('.font-selection').change(function() {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();

    if (val == 'Arial_0')
        $textpreview.addClass('arial');
    else if(val == 'Mango Smoothie_1')
        $textpreview.addClass('mango');
    else if(val == 'Bombshell_2')
        $textpreview.addClass('bombshell');
    else if(val == 'Monogram_3')
        $textpreview.addClass('monogram');
    else if(val == 'Cursive_4')
        $textpreview.addClass('cursive');
    else if(val == 'Noteworthy_5')
        $textpreview.addClass('noteworthy');
    else if(val == 'Sign Painter_6')
        $textpreview.addClass('signpainter');
    else if(val == 'Typewriter_7')
        $textpreview.addClass('typewriter');
    else
        $textpreview.removeClass('no-font');
});
```

Also here is an example product that I am using it on: http://dts.wahhadesign.com/product/custom-handwriting-bar-necklace-with-the-writing-or-art-of-your-little-one-or-loved-one/

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you remove the font classes no longer needed prior to the if/else.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Logan, it completely solves the issue - which the OP will confirm, as he confirmed with me yesterday.  How does this not solve/answer the errors?